# Create empty rows in a Word table with help of VBA

Tags: ms-word

I have a table in Word (I am using Office 365) with nine columns in every row.
See the attached pictures.
I want the macro to make an empty row as soon as the first column changing value.
The empty row should be placed betwen two different values in column 1.

[Before activate the macro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDyyr.png)
[After activate the macro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyZgq.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.